# how to associate data schema in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to associate 2 schema on nodejs/mongoose app.
my first model:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var projectSchema = new Schema({
  pname: String,
  pnumber: String,
  plocation: String,
  pclient: String,
  clientabn: String,
  contname: String,
  contnumber: String,
  mobile: String,
  address: String,
  city: String,
  country: String,
  boqs: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Boq",
  }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Project", projectSchema);
```

second model:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var boqSchema = new Schema({
    boqDesc: String,
    boqUnit: String,
    boqQty: String,
    boqRate: String,
    boqPrice: String,

});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Boq", boqSchema);
```

And this is my post rout:

```
app.post("/myprojects/:id/boq", function(req, res) {
  Project.findById(req.params.id, function(err, project) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      Boq.create(req.body.boq, function(err, boq) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          project.boqs.push(boq);
          project.save();
          res.redirect("/myprojects/" + project._id + "/boq");
          console.log(boq);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

When is posting, only an id of boq will be saved on database not any data from boq's form. anyone knows what is wrong with this code?
output of console.log:
[console.log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwbPq.png)

[console.log(project)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWqx8.png)

Below is the post form:

```
<form action="/myprojects/<%= project._id %>/boq" method="POST">
   <table class="table" id="toptab">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td class="td6"><b>No.</b></td>
            <td class="td7"><b>Item Description/Scope of Work</b></td>
            <td class="td8"><b>Unit</b></td>
            <td class="td9"><b>Quantity</b></td>
            <td class="td10"><b>Rate</b></td>
            <td class="td11"><b>Price</b></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td6"></td>
            <td class="td7" contenteditable="true" name="boq[boqDesc]"></td>
            <td class="td8" contenteditable="true" name="boq[boqUnit]"></td>
            <td class="td9" contenteditable="true" name="boq[boqQty]"></td>
            <td class="td10" contenteditable="true" name="boq[boqRate]">$</td>
            <td class="td11" contenteditable="true" name="boq[boqPrice]"></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: can you please add a console.log(req.body.boq) output...

Comment: I added console.log

Comment: is that console.log(boq) or console.log(req.body.boq) you've added to the question?

Comment: console.log(boq)

Comment: can you please add a console.log(req.body.boq) before the create call and add the output to your question?

Comment: I just did and the outcome is "undefined"...so there's something wrong with getting data from the form?

Comment: exactly, see answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're calling  `Boq.create(undefined, callback);`

this creates a boq document in db with no fields (except the _id).

it passes validation because all boq's fields are not required.

---

go to your client, and make sure you're adding boq data to http request's body correctly.

add `<input>` elements in between `<td></td>` tags, each named after one of the fields in boq's schema. for instance `<td><input type="text" name="boqDesc"></td>`

Comment: I just added the form to my question, can you please have a look and see what is wrong with that?

Comment: why not use `<input>` elements inside the table's `<td>`?

Comment: happens to the best of them. i'd appreciate it if you ticked my answer if it helped solve your problem/s.

Comment: you're the best thank you. I just started to learn programing with Nodejs and come across lots of problem, it is frustrating but should be normal in programing world. I'm about to send another question. maybe you can help me with that one as well